# Find and update with forEach does not work

Tags: node.js, mongoose

Every Project has many tasks. And the tasks have start date time field, it may be delayed due to some reasons, So each tasks for the particular project should be delayed and updated by the given minutes. I tried the following code but it does not update the time by the given delay duration, please.

```
function delayAllTasks(req, res, next)
{
    const givenProjectId = req.body.project_id;
    var delays_by = req.body.delays_by;

    try
    {
        Task.find({ project_id: givenProjectId }).exec((err, tasks) => {
            tasks.forEach((eachTasks) => {                
                Task.update(   { project_id: givenProjectId }, //where query
                               { $set: { estimate_start_datetime: moment(eachTasks.estimate_start_datetime).add(delays_by, 'minutes') } } //what to be changed
                           ).then(function (updatedDelays)
                            {                                
                                return res.status(200).json("updated", updatedDelays);
                            }).catch(function (err)
                            {
                                return res.status(503).json(err);
                            });
            })
        })
    }
    catch (err)
    {
        return res.status(500).json(err);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would make sure your query is finding the tasks correctly.. I would log the task count found by the Task.find query. The code is working for me as long as the Task.find returns tasks to update.

```
function delayAllTasks(req, res, next)
{
    const givenProjectId = req.body.project_id;
    var delays_by = req.body.delays_by;

    Task.find({ project_id: givenProjectId }).exec((err, tasks) => {
            console.log("Updating task count:", tasks ? tasks.length: 0);
            tasks.forEach((eachTasks) => {
```

...

Comment: So, what should I want to do?

Comment: I would log the task count so we know that tasks are actually being found for the query. I would also consider logging the err object, this may not be null. The try / catch won't see any errors from the query.

Comment: yeah! I also used this `console.log("Updating task count:", tasks ? tasks.length: 0);` line, it returns the number of tasks for that particular project

Comment: Do you see any tasks being updated, e.g. a non-zero count. I'm just suspecting that no tasks are being found for the project id.

Comment: it shows `Updating task count: 14` but not updating

Comment: What format is the task -> estimate_start_datetime in? is it a string, or a unix timestamp? thank you!

Comment: It is `date` as follows :  `estimate_start_datetime: { type: Date, required: true },`